# copy list of files in a folder to another folder

Tags: vbscript, dos

I have a folder with approx 10000 images, and I need to copy about 500 of them to another folder.

If I create a list of the files I want to copy, how could I copy the files the files?

Was thinking vbscript or is it possible thorough DOS commands such as Xcopy using switches?

Thanks,

Comment: How are you creating the list of files? Do they match some simple criteria?

Comment: yes the list of files will be in a textfile...e.g.image1.jpg \n image2.jpg etc etc...Looking at the answers below I think I'll be using one of those shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming that you had the list of files in a text file, here's a vbscript

```
Set objFS=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
strFile = objArgs(0)
strDestination = objArgs(1)
Set objFile =objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfLine
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    objfs.CopyFile strLine,strDestination &"\"&strLine
Loop
```

save as myscript.vbs and on command line

```
C:\test>more file
test1.txt
test2.txt

c:\test> cscript //nologo myscript.vbs file c:\destination\directory
```

OR if you want batch

```
@echo off
for /F %%i in (file) do (  copy "%%i" c:\destination   )
```

if you want to move list of files according to some pattern, just do

```
c:\test> copy *pattern*.txt c:\destination
```

Answer (score 2):

For a one-off on the command line, prepare a filenames.txt, one name per line. Then issue:

```
for /f %n in (filenames.txt) do copy "%n" "t:\arget\folder"
```

for VBScript, you can achieve the same thing using `Scripting.FileSystemObject` and it's close relatives (like the `File` and `Folder` objects), but in comparison this is more complicated. ghostdog74's answer shows one way.